# Website not responsive on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, samsung-mobile

A Wordpress website (using the Genesis framework) I've designed to be responsive displays properly on an iPhone and a HTC but doesn't on Samsung Galaxy phones. (tested on Samsung Galaxy S2 and a Samsung Ace) I'm currently using the FitVids plugin to make the video embeds responsive.

Strangely, pages with no video embeds viewed on a Samsung phone displays properly, but on a page with video embeds, the page layout displayed is that for an tablet screen and not for a phone screen.

I've tried various other plugins but none of them seem to solve this problem.

It would be great if someone could offer any advice on this.

Here's My [site](http://testsite101.com/jooja)

Here's the css [stylesheet](http://testsite101.com/jooja/wp-content/themes/jooja_theme/style.css?ver=1.9.1)

Comment: You are using `jquery.fitvids.js` version `1.0` from 2011 - maybe you should check for updates.

Comment: please found my post, and try that by putting in media css

Comment: I'd love to see a good answer to this; none of the answers provided address why a page with video embeds functions differently than one without.

Answer (score 3):

As i have found that samsung screen is 480*800px

Please try with below CSS:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 480px) 
and (max-device-width : 800px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 480px) 
and (max-device-width : 800px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try using this

```
<meta content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" name="viewport">
```

Comment: If you explain what this code does you would likely receive more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended that you use @media rules, since the pixel size on a mobile device vs desktop may vary.

For instance, instead of:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 480px) 
and (max-device-width : 800px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {

}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 480px) 
and (max-device-width : 800px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {

}
```

Add a container that will have a margin-left of 5% and margin-right of 5%:

```
<body>
<div class="container">
# Your body goes here
</div>
</body>
```

I have found this a much more user friendly and maintained approach to responsive design than the standard @media rule.